# I would like to mark all updated rows with the date that they have been updated

Tags: sql, sql-server-express

After updating rows in a table I would like to mark all the updated rows with the date that they have been updated.

What code do i need to write to do this

p.s.   I should have stated that i am updating using a view because it helps me see clearly what data needs updating.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Use triggers for this kind of work, only safe way to make sure it's always done!

Comment: @jarlh Your experience may differ, but in mine, triggers that change records behind the application's back are likely to break those applications, if those applications retrieve a record, post one update, don't re-load the record, then attempt to post another update.

Comment: Sql server express 2014

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a trigger that fires after update to do this.

Given a table like:
`create table your_table (id int primary key, val int, last_update datetime)`

this trigger will set the `last_update` value whenever you update something in the table.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name ON your_table
AFTER UPDATE AS 
    BEGIN
       UPDATE your_table
       SET your_table.last_update = GETDATE()
       FROM your_table t
       JOIN inserted i ON t.id = i.id
    END
```

For the complete syntax and options for the trigger, see [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx).

Comment: i am updating using a view. will triggers be a problem. i have never used them before. i am studying Sql atm.

Comment: @frustrationmultiplied It depends on the view, but if it allows updates then I don't think it should be any problem.

Comment: thanks. can you explain how the above code works. from my reading of it it is just marking the last record that was updated.

Comment: @frustrationmultiplied When you use a trigger a couple of virtual tables (`inserted` and `deleted`) are used that hold the data that was modified. By joining the table that was updated with the `inserted` table the trigger will update the set will all rows that matches. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx for more information.

Comment: Thats great. thanks for the clear explanation. Thanks to everyone else who helped also.

Answer (score 0):

If you have option to do in application or Database, Application is better way for doing this. (For example in BaseDAL class)

If the application is not an option you can do it in database Trigger and updating the rows.

Comment: can you expalin what BaseDAL is

Comment: BaseDAL might be a base class for all of your database operations, it is a sample name and I was meant if you have this in your application you can use it